# Entropy for text in python

Tags: python

I need to find the entropy of a text.

I want to use the Shannon Entropy.

So my input is a dictionary consisting a text document of a book (all the words) and its frequencies. The output should be the entropy for the observed probabilities of all the words. Right now my code is like this:

```
import math 

def shannon(string):
        prob = [ float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dict.fromkeys(list(string)) ]
        entropy = sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in prob ])
        return entropy
```

Where boe is the dictionary consisting of the words and frequencies and i first transfrom it into a string so that the code works. However, im not sure if this is the correct entropy for this case.

Comment: Your function doesn't use `word_map`.

Comment: You keep redoing and undoing all the operations over and over. E.g. `boe` is a `dict`, then you convert it to `str`, then to `list`, then back to `dict`. What's up with that?

Comment: I think you need to put some careful thought into what you are really trying to do, what your inputs are and how you want to use them. Then (again carefully) write your thoughts into code. 'Cause what you have here is borderline gibberish.

Comment: Also, use `math.log2` in preference to `math.log(x, 2)`, which in turn is better than `math.log(x) / math.log(2)`.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want the word (rather than character) entropy of your text. Also, that you define `P(w)` to be the frequency of the word divided by the total number of words in the text:

```
from math import log2

def shannon(boe):
    total = sum(boe.values()) 
    return sum(freq / total * log2(total / freq) for freq in boe.values())

shannon(boe)
```

The probability requires the total word count. If you do not pass that in externally, you can get it as the sum of all the frequencies: `sum(boe.values())`. The return value in the function is just `p * log2(1/p)`, given that `p` is `freq / total`.

Comment: Should there also be a sign reversal for the return value per the formula for entropy?

Comment: @Gaurav. It's been a while since I answered this, so you may be right. My guess it's a matter of convention. I always do a simple sanity check for some known inputs.